# Can I use `man` for a command in a specified path?

Tags: unix, manpage

In my CentOS server, I have two commands: `/bin/vi` and `/usr/local/bin/vi`.

If `/usr/local/bin/vi` presents before `/bin/vi` in `PATH`, `man vi` will show the man page for `/usr/local/bin/vi`.

How can I get man page for `/bin/vi` then? I have tried `man /bin/vi`, but it did not work.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic as it's not a programming question. Try asking at http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: what is the difference?

Comment: @mcalex One is `vi`, the other is `vim`, and I just take these two for an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know where the man page for /bin/vi is kept?  If so, set the environmental variable MANPATH to point to that directory, or add it at the beginning.

```
export MANPATH=/mymanpath:$MANPATH
```